# NSFetchedResultsController doesn't know data was changed with a NSBatchUpdateRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsbatchupdaterequest

### TL;DR

Apparently, `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't know data was changed on a given `NSManagedObjectContext` when that change happens by executing a `NSBatchUpdateRequest`. Is it possible to force `NSFetchedResultsController` to reload its data so `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` on `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` gets called?

### The problem

I'm using a fetched results controller to be informed about changes in the underlying data so I can update my table view when it changes. I'm adopting the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol and implementing the `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` method. Everything seems to be working, because the did change method it's called when I insert, delete or update individual items.

The problem happens when I'm batch-updating several items with `NSBatchUpdateRequest`. When I do that, the delegate method `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` is not called (I'm executing these updates in the same context used by the fetched results controller).

### Code

**#1: Fetched results controller initialization:**

```
func createFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EAlbum> = NSFetchRequest<EAlbum>(entityName: "EAlbum")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: createPredicates())
    addSortDescriptors(on: fetchRequest)

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                              managedObjectContext: AppDelegate.myPersistentContainer.viewContext,
                                                              sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                              cacheName: nil)

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

**#2: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate:**

```
extension FeedTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
                    didChange anObject: Any,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                    newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        default:
            // TODO
        }
    }

}
```

**#3: Function where I use `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to update a bunch of items from `AppDelegate.myPersistentContainer.viewContext`:**

```
func markAllAsRead(using context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "EAlbum")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", #keyPath(EAlbum.markUnread))
    request.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(EAlbum.markUnread): false]
    request.resultType = .statusOnlyResultType

    do {
        let result = try context.execute(request) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
        return result?.result as? Bool ?? false
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

**#4: Function where I update just one item from `AppDelegate.myPersistentContainer.viewContext`:**

```
func updateUnreadFlag(albumId: String, markUnread: Bool, using context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    guard let album = try? EAlbum.findAlbum(matching: albumId, in: context) else { return }
    album.markUnread = markUnread
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

When **#4** is called, the delegate `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` method is called. But when executing **#3**, the delegate method does not get called. It seems like `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't know that data was changed on a given `NSManagedObjectContext` when that change happens by executing a `NSBatchUpdateRequest`.

### Workaround I've tried

Since my fetched results controller doesn't know that data was changed, I thought about reloading it by hand like so:

```
func reloadFetchedResultsController() {
    fetchedResultsController = createFetchedResultsController()

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So everytime after **#3** is executed, I would call `reloadFetchedResultsController()` to reload the fetched results controller and the table view. But for some reason it seems that it loads the old data, because nothing changes on my table view.

### Questions

**A:** Is it possible to let a fetched results controller know that data was changed when executing a batch update?

**B:** Is it possible to force my fetched results controller to reload its data? Because, as a last resort, I could force a reload on my fetched results controller after executing **#3**, and finally force a table view update after that, so it would reload it's cells using the newly batch-updated data from the fetched results controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchUpdates/BatchUpdates.html):

After executing the batch update request you have to merge the changes into the context.

Try

```
func markAllAsRead(using context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "EAlbum")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", #keyPath(EAlbum.markUnread))
    request.propertiesToUpdate = [#keyPath(EAlbum.markUnread): false]
    request.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType

    do {
        let result = try context.execute(request) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
        guard let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] else { return false }
        let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey : objectIDArray]
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [context])
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```